# If the initial target of the Hex spell is reduced to 0 HP, can the curse be moved to an unseen target or one out of range?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

To originally cast the spell *hex*, you must target "a creature you can see within range". The spell says that if the target drops to 0 hit points before the spell ends, the caster can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn to move the curse to a new creature. However, it does not say that the new creature being cursed has to be seen or within range.

If the initial target of *hex* is reduced to 0 HP, can the curse be moved to an unseen target or one out of range?

Rules as Written, it seems possible to do so, but that seems a bit overpowered.

Comment: Related: [Does the Hex spell require a Clear Path when moved to a second target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168352/does-the-hex-spell-require-a-clear-path-when-moved-to-a-second-target)

Answer (score 13):

### The "see within range" part still applies.

The spell states:

> **You place a curse** on a creature that you can see within range. [description of effects]
>   If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours **to curse a new creature**.
>   [...]

It allows you to apply the curse to another creature. The procedure of applying this curse is described earlier in the spell's description, and the phrasing limits the target selection to be within range and sight.

Cursing a target when you cast the spell is no different from moving it to another creature later on, at least not concerning target validity.

I suppose that RAW, you could read this differently if you were intent on it. However, common sense tells us that the spell *clearly* isn't supposed to work the way you asked.