# Does the Hex spell require a Clear Path when moved to a second target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, line-of-effect

The [*Hex*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex) spell reads (PHB, p. 251):

> You place a curse on a creature that you can see within
>   range. [...]
>
> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature.

*Hex* still requires range and sight requirements to be satisfied when re-applying because of the first line of its description but I am uncertain whether the targeting limitations apply when the spell is not being cast?

The precise situation I am thinking of is moving *Hex* to a target that is visible through a transparent window. I suspect the answer is no but would appreciate a deeper understanding.

A related component of this question is whether moving *Hex* is considered to be moving the effect or having multiple targets.

Relevant:

- [Does reapplying Hex have any spell components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72738/does-reapplying-hex-have-any-spell-components)
- [If the initial target of the Hex spell is reduced to 0 HP, can the curse be moved to an unseen target or one out of range?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120052/changing-hex-to-unseen-targets-out-of-range)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It depends on whether your GM thinks you target somebody when you move *hex*

In Chapter 10: Spellcasting there is the ["A Clear Path to the Target"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget) section, which states:

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover. [...]

This applies to all instances of a spell targeting somebody - but does moving *hex* to a new creature actually target them?

Furthermore the section on ["Total Cover"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TotalCover) states:

> A target with total cover can't be targeted directly by an attack or a spell, although some spells can reach such a target by including it in an area of effect. A target has total cover if it is completely concealed by an obstacle.

If somebody is behind a window, and thus has total cover, they cannot be targeted by a spell. We run into the same question, does *hex* target somebody when you move it to a new creature?

The follow Q/A discusses this in relation to the Sorcerer's Twinned Spell Metamagic:

- [Can Hex be Twinned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132921)

And this Q/A discusses what count as spell targets in general:

- [What counts as a target for a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152115)

There is plenty of debate as to what counts as a target. There's a reason Twinned Spell is asked about so frequently here and it's because what counts as a target for a spell is not particularly clear. Plenty of people disagree so you're going to have to ask your GM whether *hex* targets somebody when you move it. If it does, then a window will stop it.

### What this GM would rule

I would say that *hex* targets somebody when you move it. You are actively choosing to affect a creature with the spell and for me that it sufficient to conclude that you are targeting them.

Comment: Rules designer Jeremy Crawford concurs with your ruling in [a series of (unofficial) tweets from November 2016](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/28/can-you-cast-hunters-mark-on-a-target-out-of-range-of-the-initial-target-if-it-goes-down/) about *hunter's mark*, a very similar spell: "The intent is that any creature you target with any spell—including hunter's mark—must be within the spell's range. [...] In a spell, targeting is bound by the spell's range. The effects aren't bound by it."

Comment: @V2Blast Yeah there's actually a large number of Crawford quotes supporting this. This is one of those much-debated things for 5e and I've seen so many arguments about what counts as a target. I haven't seen Crawford's tweets sway most people yet so I chose not to include them.